# MGWT permutations size for a very simple app

Tags: mgwt

I just started to created a simple app with MGWT, and so far I have:

- 1 Activty/Place/view (containing a scrolling panel, 3 buttons and 3 inputs)
- 1 HistoryObserver
- 1 ActivityMapper
- 1 AnimationMapper

After compiling I can see that the permutations are ~ 170ko.
It seems a bit big just for such a small app. Is it normal? Is it the minimal size for a MGWT app?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any of this in your GWT XML? When I removed this, my permutation count decreased dramatically. There are right ways and wrong ways to use this, which I haven't gotten around to yet:

`<inherits name="com.googlecode.mgwt.ui.client.theme.platform.Platform"/>
<set-configuration-property name="mgwt.css" value="pretty"/>
<set-property name="mgwt.os" value="android"/>`